# Update DataSet structure in Visual Studio to match new SQL Database Structure

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, ado.net, dataset

After making some changes to my SQL database structure (using scripts in SQL Server Management Studio), how can I update my DataSet.xsd file in Visual Studio to match the new structure?  Must I do this manually?
I considered deleting the DataSet and importing a new one, but I'll lose all my custom Table Adapter queries.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

From the [MSDN Forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/95d5b943-3641-4955-acac-287d21760d4f):

> If you right-click the TableAdapter in the Dataset Designer and click
>   'Configure' the TableAdapter Configuration Wizard opens where you can
>   reconfigure the main query that defines the schema of your table. This
>   should leave the additional TableAdapter queries (the additional
>   methods) that were added after initial configuration.
>
> Of course the additional methods will also need to be reconfigured if they reference a column that has been removed from the table on the
>   database, or if any of the column definitions change (for example, if
>   the data type is changed or modified). So if an aditional column was
>   added to the table and it allows Null values the existing methods
>   should still work - just depends on the scope of change to the schema
>   of the table in the database.

Comment: Thanks a lot, a great work of returning and improving quality of the answer for the community after passage of one year. Really appreciated and useful information.

Comment: What if I need to update the DataSet.xsd because I added not just some columns on some tables but some brand new tables or views?

Comment: "Configure" option is disabled on my end. what to do?

Comment: Yup, same here..  "Configure" is disabled...   I can delete the table, then re-add it from Server Explorer, but it loses all the relationships.