# DataSet.Designer.vb does not get updated

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I have added some fields in my database table and added them on my dataset with the help of the wizard. In my code I have two queries an insert and update which do not pick up the changes made to the dataset.

This means that they are some somehow forgotten to get updated.
Therefore, when I type this:

```
Me.TransactionTableAdapter.updTransaction(1,2,3)
```

it works using the previous database version instead of being like this

```
Me.TransactionTableAdapter.updTransaction(1,2,3,4)
```

Any ideas how to get it updated without editing the Dataset.Designer.vb file?

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9497689/update-dataset-structure-in-visual-studio-to-match-new-sql-database-structure and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16967155/how-do-i-get-visual-studio-2010-to-refresh-my-dataset-after-i-have-updated-the-d

Comment: @Neolisk  Not sure that the issue should not be considered as a duplicate, but done;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is related to:

- [Update DataSet structure in Visual Studio to match new SQL Database Structure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9497689/2387010)
- [How do I get Visual Studio 2010 to refresh my DataSet after I have updated the Database source?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16967155/2387010) which provides another link to [How to: Edit TableAdapters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171902%28VS.80%29.aspx) on MSDN