# vb .net with access database, how to apply changes from .accdb to the dataset in visual studio?

Tags: .net, database, vb.net

i'm working on a project with Visual Studio (vb .net) and an Access database. I need to change some of the tables/columns in my database, so i just went into the .accdb file and changed some stuff. now the question is how do i apply these changes to my existing database in Visual Studio? Do i have to remove the existing database and re-add the modified one? This makes a lot of mess with the auto-generated code of Visual Studio, and then i need to fix it manually - not ideal at all. Is there another, more elegant way of doing it?

Thank you

Comment: The very first time that I used a database (SQL or Access) with Visual Studio, I let VS handle all the dirty work. I ran into a similar problem to yours, and since then I just write all the queries and do everything with my own code. Much easier to manage IMO

Comment: I totally agree, but how? how can i access to an .accdb file without importing it as a "database" in visual studio?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17002768/dataset-designer-vb-does-not-get-updated/17013081#17013081

Comment: You just do OLeDB queries to the .accdb file. You just need to know the path of the database. In my case it's usually just the Application.StartupPath

Comment: Well, i'm not familiar with enough ULeDB commands, and anyway i'm too far out into the project to change it all. But i'm definitely going to do this next time! Is there a good website with ULeDB commands and examples?

Answer (score 0):

If you did something to your columns in your DB especially Insert .. so should change your code if access the column/field by **column index** .. but if you access them by column name, you shouldn't make any big changes ..

Comment: Yes of course i will change any code that relies on tables/columns that i deleted from the .accdb file. But the thing is that visual studio doesn't "see" the changes i made to the .accdb file. If i go to database->tables i only see the tables from before i made the changes.