# Refresh dataset on change the structure of access database

Tags: visual-studio, dataset

I have a dataset that uses an access .mdb database. How do I synchronize the dataset when I make changes to the access database?

Edit: I mean: if I add a table or change its structure in the Access mdb, the DataSet in Visual Studio does not update. I've tried the Refresh menu item, but I still see the old structure.

Comment: Not sure if you are talking about typed dataset. See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9497689/update-dataset-structure-in-visual-studio-to-match-new-sql-database-structure/9497756#9497756

Comment: I mean: if I add a table or change its structure in the access mdb, the DataSet in Visual Studio does not update. I've tried the Refresh menu item, but I still see the old structure.

Answer (score 0):

Because the **dataset** and the information in it that is available in the visual studio, is a copy of mdb file information. that can be sent to the **dataset** or from the **dataset** to mdb by `sqlDataAdapter`. For this reason, the edited information in the mdb file is not displayed in the program, because after editing, the information must be retrieved by the **dataset** from mdb file.

sorry for my English...

Comment: So every time I make a change on the access db do I have to recreate the dataset?

Comment: @IfThenElse yes, If the information of a table, there is no need to rebuild it, but if the table structure changes, you need to re-create that